# Remove text inside parentheses at the end of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex which finds a string present in parenthesis & remove it like I have below sample string where I want this to perform:

```
09373 837 937 (mobile) // Output should be "09373 837 937"
9838373838 (home) // Output should be "9838373838"
+19383947388 (home) // Output should be "+19383947388"
(938)3947388 (mobile) // Output should be "(938)3947388"
```

So the first part will always be contact a number which could be in any format & the last part will always be label, I want to remove that label

Comment: `String.replace(/\s*\(.*?$/, '')`

Comment: You need `.replace(/\s*\([^()]*\)$/, '')` or `.replace(/\s*\([^)]*\)\s*$/, '')` or even `.replace(/[^\S\r\n]*\([^)]*\)\s*$/, '')`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks this worked, can you please post it to answers so I can accept it

Comment: Unless you describe what you have tried, I will better keep that inside the comment.

Comment: the first one only I tried and that worked: .replace(/\s*\([^()]*\)$/, '')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
.replace(/\s*\([^()]*\)$/, '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lQ0dL6/1).

If you need to make sure you only remove *horizonatal* whitespaces*, replace the `\s*` with `[^\S\r\n]*`.

**Pattern explanation**:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces (replace with `[^\S\r\n]` to match horizontal whitespace, i.e. `\s` with `\r` and `\n` "subtracted" from it)
- `\(` - a literal `(` symbol
- `[^()]*` - zero or more symbols other than `(` and `)` (replace with `[^)]*` if there can be `(` inside the parentheses)
- `\)` - a closing `)`
- `$` - end of string.

```js
var re = /\s*\([^()]*\)$/g; 
var strs = ['09373 837 937 (mobile)','9838373838 (home)','+19383947388 (home)','(938)3947388 (mobile)'];
for (var s = 0; s < strs.length; s++) {                  // Demo
  document.body.innerHTML += "Replacing in \"<i>" + strs[s] + "</i>\"... ";
  document.body.innerHTML += "Result: <b>\"" + strs[s].replace(re, '') + "\"</b><br/>";
}
```